# Proving that (α → β) ⊢ (α → ¬¬β) in Propositional Calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $L$<sub>0</sub> = $L$ [{¬, →}]. Define the system $L$<sub>0</sub> as follows:

An axiom of $L$<sub>0</sub> is any formula of $L$<sub>0</sub> of the form

- (A1) $(α → (β → α))$
- (A2) $((α → (β → γ) → ((α→β) → (β→γ)))$
- (A3) $((¬β → ¬α) → (α → β))$

The only rule of inference in $L$<sub>0</sub> is modus ponens, i.e. from $α$ and $(α→β)$ infer $β$.

How could we go about proving $(α → β) ⊢ (α → ¬¬β)$, and vice versa: $(α → ¬¬β) ⊢ (α → β)$? I have proved that $(α → ¬¬α)$ is a tautology so we may use this.

Comment: You could take a book on proof theory, derive some more inference rules (natural deduction or sequent calculus) and go from there. It is unnecessary hard work to use only one inference rule. You can for instance look at the first chapter of an introduction to proof theory, normalization, cut-elimination and consistency

Comment: Do you have the Deduction Theorem? It needs A1 and A2 to be proved.

Answer (score 1):

I have not taken the route of proving natural deduction rules first, instead, I go directly from your Hilbert-style axioms. I have also not used the deduction theorem.
I have however taken the liberty to switch axiom 2 with
$$ ((\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \gamma)) \rightarrow ((\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \gamma))) $$
as your A2 is not even a tautology in classical logic. I believe this is the axiom you intended.

Theorems we will use:
$$A \rightarrow B \text{ and } B \rightarrow C \vdash A \rightarrow C \quad \textbf{(T1)}$$
$$A \rightarrow \neg \neg A \quad \textbf{(T2)}$$
$$(\neg A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A \quad \textbf{(T3)}$$
$$(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C \vdash \neg A \rightarrow C \quad \textbf{(T4)}$$

**Theorem 1:** $A \rightarrow B \vdash A \rightarrow \neg \neg B$ 
Proof.

1. $A \rightarrow B$ $\quad$ (assumption)
2. $B \rightarrow \neg \neg B$ $\quad$ (T2 for $A "=" B$)
3. $A \rightarrow B \text{ and } B \rightarrow \neg \neg B \vdash A \rightarrow \neg \neg B$ $\quad$ (T1 for $A "=" A, B "=" B, C "=" \neg \neg B$)
4. $A \rightarrow \neg \neg B$ $\quad$ (1., 2., 3.)

**Theorem 2:** $A \rightarrow \neg \neg B \vdash A \rightarrow B$

First we prove: $\neg \neg A \rightarrow A$ $\quad$ **(T5)** 
Proof.

1. $(\neg A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A$ $\quad$ (T3 for $A "=" A$)
2. $(\neg A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A \vdash \neg \neg A \rightarrow A$ $\quad$ (T4 for $A "=" \neg A, B "=" A, C "=" A$)
3. $\neg \neg A \rightarrow A$ $\quad$ (1., 2.)

Then we prove Theorem 2. 
Proof.

1. $A \rightarrow \neg \neg B$ $\quad$ (assumption)
2. $\neg \neg B \rightarrow B$ $\quad$ (T5 for $A "=" B$)
3. $A \rightarrow \neg \neg B \text{ and } \neg \neg B \rightarrow B \vdash A \rightarrow B$ $\quad$ (T1 for $A "=" A, B "=" \neg \neg B, C "=" B$)
4. $A \rightarrow B$ $\quad$ (1., 2., 3.)